# add each button DOM data attribute

Tags: jquery

I have each button different `ID` and I want Take each button data attribute `title` text and add new custom data attribute `prefix`.

My html booking list where is buttons and I have to add `data-prefix` value for each button:

```
<div class="booked-appt-list shown" style="display: block;">
    <div class="timeslot bookedClearFix timeslot-count-hidden has-title ">
        <span class="timeslot-time">
            <span class="timeslot-title">Exclusive studio - #KO</span>
            <span class="timeslot-range"><i class="booked-icon booked-icon-clock"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;14:45 – 16:45</span>
        </span>
        <span class="timeslot-people">
            <button id="ddPrefixBtn_12" data-prefix="" data-calendar-id="0" data-title="Exclusive studio" data-timeslot="1445-1645" data-date="2021-09-20" class="new-appt button">
                <span class="timeslot-mobile-title">Exclusive studio - #KO</span>
                <span class="button-timeslot">14:45 – 16:45</span><span class="button-text">Book Appointment</span>
            </button>
        </span>
    </div>

    <div class="timeslot bookedClearFix timeslot-count-hidden has-title ">
        <span class="timeslot-time">
            <span class="timeslot-title">Prime studio - #SP</span>
            <span class="timeslot-range"><i class="booked-icon booked-icon-clock"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;17:15 – 19:15</span>
        </span>
        <span class="timeslot-people">
            <button id="ddPrefixBtn_13" data-prefix="" data-calendar-id="0" data-title="Prime studio" data-timeslot="1715-1915" data-date="2021-09-20" class="new-appt button">
                <span class="timeslot-mobile-title">Prime studio - #SP</span>
                <span class="button-timeslot">17:15 – 19:15</span>
                <span class="button-text">Book Appointment</span>
            </button>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have select option what Will show only that selected bookings. Select option has already `data-prefix`:

```
<div class="booked-serviceSwitcher calendar">
    <p>
        <i class="booked-icon booked-icon-calendar"></i>
        <select class="booked_calendar_chooser" id="change_service_booked">
            <option class="level-0" data-prefix="SP">Party</option>
            <option class="level-0" data-prefix="KO">School</option>
        </select>
    </p>
</div>
```

What I've tried:

```
let t = $('[id*=ddPrefixBtn_]').data('title');
let n = $('#change_service_booked').find(':selected').attr('data-prefix');
$('[id*=ddPrefixBtn_]').data('prefix', t+' - #'+n);
console.log("1:"+n);
console.log("2:"+t);
console.log("3:"+$('[id*=ddPrefixBtn_]').data('prefix'));

let selected = $('#change_service_booked').find(':selected').data('prefix');
$('.dataIdTarget').hide();
$('*[data-idTarget="'+selected+'"]').show();
$('*[data-preTarget="'+selected+'"]').show();
```

At the moment it add all buttons same `data-prefix`

Comment: There's no overload on `.data` to apply a function to each item separately (like this is for eg .text((i,txt) =>` - so you need to loop through each button and add your prefix accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

There's no overload on `.data()` to apply a function to each item separately (like there is for eg `.text((i,txt) =>` - so you need to loop through each button and add your prefix accordingly:

```
$('[id*=ddPrefixBtn_]').each(function(i, e) {
  let t = $(this).data('title');
  let n = $('#change_service_booked').find(':selected').data('prefix');
  $(this).data('prefix', t+' - #'+n);
  console.log("1:"+n);
  console.log("2:"+t);
  console.log("3:"+$(this).data('prefix'));
});
```

With a minor efficiency improvement:

```
let n = $('#change_service_booked').find(':selected').data('prefix');
console.log("1:"+n);
$('[id*=ddPrefixBtn_]').each(function(i, e) {
  let t = $(this).data('title');
  $(this).data('prefix', t+' - #'+n);
  console.log("2:"+t);
  console.log("3:"+$(this).data('prefix'));
});
```